# Economise space with floats

Tags: floats, positioning

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\lipsum[5]{1-14}
\lipsum[6][1]
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

By an inspection one can conclude that the trailing paragraph can neatly be placed on bottom at the same page as the floats. How to achieve this?

(In fact they collapse on the same page when the width of the graphics is reduced to `0.5\textwidth`.)

Comment: you are asking a lot of float questions some have had unique feature making answers worthwhile but really this is just a special case of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017 you can't ask a new question for every possible float combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\lipsum[5]{1-14}
\lipsum[6][1]
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Choose the correct specifier, here `[!ht]` will do what you want.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\lipsum[5]{1-14}
\lipsum[6][1]
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1][1-5]

\end{document}
```

> [image]